# android change view from carousel to custom listview

Tags: android, listview

i was facing the problem to modified views, project is using carousel view but now need to change to custom listview

from this `public class ProfileControlFragment extends Fragment {` carousel view begin

```
public class ProfileControlFragment extends Fragment {
....
private CarouselPagerAdapter mAdapter;
/**
 * Setting the CarouselView with data
 */
private void setCarouselView() {

    // Getting the number of services discovered
    mPages = ServiceDiscoveryFragment.mGattServiceData.size();
    FIRST_PAGE = mPages * LOOPS / 2;

    // Setting the adapter
    mAdapter = new CarouselPagerAdapter(getActivity(),
            ProfileControlFragment.this, getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager(),
            ServiceDiscoveryFragment.mGattServiceData);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mAdapter);
    mPager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    if (mPages == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.toast_no_services_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.toast_swipe_profiles), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

this the carousel adapter

```
public class CarouselPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
....
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, BluetoothGattService>> mCurrentServiceData;

public CarouselPagerAdapter(Activity context,
                            ProfileControlFragment containerFragment,
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                            ArrayList<HashMap<String, BluetoothGattService>> currentServiceData) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    this.mContext = (HomePageActivity) context;
    this.mContainerFragment = containerFragment;
    this.mCurrentServiceData = currentServiceData;

}
//passing data to the current fragments
    Fragment curFragment = CarouselFragment.newInstance(imageId,
            mScale, name, uuid.toString(), bgs);

    return curFragment;
}
```

and show that data ini this class

```
public class CarouselFragment extends Fragment {
.....
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.carousel_fragment_item, container, false);

    final int pos = this.getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_FRAG_POS);
    final String mName = this.getArguments().getString(EXTRA_FRAG_NAME);
    final String mUuid = this.getArguments().getString(EXTRA_FRAG_UUID);

    TextView mTv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    mTv.setText(mName);

    if (mName.equalsIgnoreCase(getResources().getString(
            R.string.profile_control_unknown_service))) {
        mService = mBleHashMap.get(mUuid);
        mCurrentUUID = mService.getUuid();

        UUID UUID_TEMPERATURE_SERVICE = UUID.fromString(TEMPERATURE_SERVICE);

        if (mCurrentUUID==UUID_TEMPERATURE_SERVICE)
        {

            mTv.setText("Temperature service");
        }



        TextView mTvUUID = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_uuid);
        mTvUUID.setText(mCurrentUUID.toString());
    }
```

please help me to change this to custom listview